# Vector in Vector with ENUM as ID

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to create a Vector of Vectors with a key, which should be an Enum.

Pseudo-Code:

```
MyContainer.at(Color::Red).at(3)
```

Can someone give me a clue, how i would do this very simple? Is there a better datastructure then vector?

I would like to segment Points in a Point-Cloud to their respective color-codes.

Comment: have you considered using a map of vectors?

Comment: Or just a plain array or `std::array` of vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `enum` values are contiguous, simply cast them to `std::size_t`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> MyContainer;
// resize it
double d = MyContainer.at(std::size_t(Color::Red)).at(3)
```

now, you'll have to make sure `MyContainer` has been resized, as had the `vector`s inside it.  `at` does not fill in the container, it simply checks bounds and throws if it is out of bounds on `vector`.

Now, as your set of points is fixed, we can do away with one `vector`.

```
enum class Color {
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue,
  count, // automatically becomes the number of elements
};
std::array< std::vector<int>, std::size_t(Color::count) > MyContainer;
MyContainer[std::size_t(Color::Red)].push_back(3);
```

Another alternative is to replace the outermost container with `std::unordered_map`, but that will be slower and less efficient.  `std::map` will be even slower.

If you use `enum` instead of `enum class`, you'll save some of the above `std::size_t` casts, but I would advise against it.  `unordered_map` needs a quick hash:

```
namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<Color> {
    std::size_t operator()(Color c) const {
      return static_cast<std::size_t>(c);
    }
  };
}
```

but again, I'd advise against this path.

A final option would be to write a custom container wrapper around `array` or `vector` that does the `std::size_t` casting for you.  I would only bother doing that kind of thing if I was going to be publishing it as a library of some kind, or if I was bored.

Comment: so when i use the one vector version and use the old-way enum, i could save the 'std::size_t' ?

Comment: "If you use enum instead of enum class, you'll save some of the above std::size_t casts..." Why.....? Why can't `enum class` just auto-convert it as well?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's like a non-answer lol. Why design it that way? Doesn't that just make everyone's life harder? What benefit is there in not allowing it to auto-convert just like a regular `enum`?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `std::map<Color, std::vector<int>>` instead.

```
enum struct Color
{
  Red,
  Blue,
};

int main()
{
  std::map<Color, std::vector<int>> m{{Color::Blue, {10,20,30}}};
  m[Color::Red] = {1,2,3,4};

  std::cout << m[Color::Red].at(3) << '\n'; // prints 4
  std::cout << m[Color::Blue][0] << '\n';   // prints 10
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb0914d94289992)

Comment: @user1767754 If your enum starts as `0` and is continuous, an array may be a better option. It would be a hash map with perfect hashing :-)

Comment: Why `map` and not `unordered_map`?

Comment: @Yakk Fewer keystrokes? Of course `unordered_map` would work too, and so would juan's array solution if the enums are contiguous. The OP will have to test and decide for himself what works best.

Comment: @juanchopanza hmmm they can be as well... then i have to ignore the front-end. If you like, you can pass a snippet

Comment: @user1767754 What do you mean by "ignore the front-end"?

Comment: @Praetoriean `map` the container you should use when you need associative lookup **and** order.  `unordered_map` when you don't need order.  (`map` needs `less`, while `unordered_map` needs `equal` and `hash`, but that is less important)

Comment: @Yakk I am aware of all that. You get ordering of the `enum` for free, not so with `hash<Color>`.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is a sequence container. If you want to map your entries to some kind of key that does not have to be consecutive then a map might be a better idea.